# Object expected In IE but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have written a function for browser compatibility. When I pass objTR.cells[0] it works in Firefox but I'm getting an error in IE.

This is my Javascript code

```
function Browser_Compability(container) {
  if (navigator.appName == "Netscape") {
  // appName for both FireFox and Chrome its is "Netscape".
    return container.textContent;
  } else {
    return container.innerText;
  }
}

function selectRow(objTR) {
  var txtSSName = document.getElementById('<%=txtSSName.ClientID%>');
  txtSSName.value=Browser_Compability(objTR.cells[0]);
}
```

### ASPX Code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSSName" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" CssClass="csstextbox"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterModalityList" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr onclick="selectRow(this);">
      <td class="csstablelisttd">
        <asp:Label ID="lblSSName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SS_NAME")%>'></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Live demo would be helpful, we don't need your server code. Also, browser detection is evil. Use `return container.textContent || container.innerText;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried using trim() it will works Fine in IE MOZILLA CHROME

```
txtSSName.value=Browser_Compability(objTR.cells[0]).trim();
```